# Messages are rejected since there are fewer in-sync replicas than required

Tags: apache-kafka

we have 3 kafka brokers with min.insync.replicas=2 and all the brokers(3) are insync .
we are getting the error Messages are rejected since there are fewer in-sync replicas than required for some of the topics.

since we have all the brokers in sync we were not expecting this error

Comment: How are you getting that the brokers are all insync? Are you sure they are insync for the topic partitions you are sending messages to? Can you provide the output of the kafka-topics.sh describe command for the topic partitions you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

`min.insync.replicas` is both a topic and broker configuration. Do you have this set anywhere else?